# Get name option and value with multi input checkbox

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a form with this entry

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[repassage]" id="options1" value="10.00"> Repassage 30 mn
<input type="checkbox" name="option[frigo]" id="options2" value="5.00"> Frigo 30 mn
```

With php i do this to get all the options and i put them in an array but i can not get the right values for 'titre_option' and 'prix_option' !!!

```
if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
    foreach ( $_POST['option'] as $key => $value ) {
        $_SESSION['option'][] = array('titre_option' => $_POST['option'][$key], 'prix_option' => $_POST['option'][$value]);
    }
}

// What i get
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [titre_option] => 10.00
            [prix_option] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [titre_option] => 5.00
            [prix_option] => 
        )

)

// What i need
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [titre_option] => repassage
            [prix_option] => 10.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [titre_option] => frigo
            [prix_option] => 5.00
        )

)
```

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$_SESSION['option'][] = array('titre_option' => $_POST['option'][$key], 'prix_option' => $_POST['option'][$value]);
```

To this

```
$_SESSION['option'][] = array('titre_option' => $key, 'prix_option' => $value);
```

Because of the foreach loop, you already have the right variables, and don't need to get them again from the array.